# Regex for words that don't differ by only one letter

Tags: regex

I want to create series of puzzle games where you change one letter in a word to create a new word, with the aim of reaching a given target word. For example, to change "this" to "that":

```
this
thin
than
that
```

What I want to do is create a regex which will scan a list of words and choose all those that *do not* match the current word by all but one letter. For example, if my starting word is "pale" and my list of words is...

```
pale
male
sale
tale
pile
pole
pace
page
pane
pave
palm

peal
leap
play
help
pack
```

... I want all the words from "peal" to "pack" to be selected. This means that I can delete them from my list, leaving only the words that could be the next match. (It's OK for "pale" itself to be unselected.)

I can do this in parts:

- `^.(?!ale).{3}\n` selects words not like "*ale"
- `^.(?<!p).{3}\n|^.{2}(?!le).{2}\n` selects words not like "p*le"
- `^.{2}(?<!pa).{2}\n|^.{3}(?!e).\n` selects words not like "pa*e"
- `^.{3}(?<!pal).\n` selects words not like "pal*".

However, when I put them together...

```
^.(?!ale).{3}\n|^.(?<!p).{3}\n|^.{2}(?!le).{2}\n|^.{2}(?<!pa).{2}\n|^.{3}(?!e).\n|^.{3}(?<!pal).\n
```

... everything but "pale" is matched.

I need some way to create an `AND` relationship between the different regexes, or (more likely) a completely different approach.

Comment: When you say a completely different approach, could it also be one without using regex? Because that would probably be best.

Comment: Also it would probably be much easier to construct a regex which matches words that differ by at most one letter and then select the words that match the regex (i.e. delete the ones that don't match) rather than your inverted approach.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Python [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module that allows fuzzy matching:

```
>>> import regex
>>> regex.findall(r'(?:pale){s<=1}', "male sale tale pile pole pace page pane pave palm peal leap play help pack")
['male', 'sale', 'tale', 'pile', 'pole', 'pace', 'page', 'pane', 'pave', 'palm']
```

In this case, you want a substitution of 0 or 1 is a match.

Or consider the [TRE library](http://laurikari.net/tre/documentation/regex-syntax/) and the command line `agrep` which supports a similar syntax.

Given:

```
$ echo $s 
male sale tale pile pole pace page pane pave palm peal leap play help pack
```

You can filter to a list of a single substitution:

```
$ echo $s | tr ' ' '\n' | agrep '(?:pale){ 1s <2 }'
male
sale
tale
pile
pole
pace
page
pane
pave
palm
```

Comment: Nice answer (and a regex solution as asked). Any idea how the performance of a fuzzy matching regex behaves compared to other solutions shown here?

Comment: As long as no back references are used -- fast.

Comment: So fuzzy regex doesn't use any back references? Interesting. Come to think about it the state machine behind the regular expression would simply need to increase a counter upon mismatch and continue to the next state. I learned something new today :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that uses cool python tricks and no regex:

```
def almost_matches(word1, word2):
    return sum(map(str.__eq__, word1, word2)) == 3

for word in "male sale tale pile pole pace page pane pave palm peal leap play help pack".split():
    print almost_matches("pale", word)
```

Answer (score 2):

A completely different approach: [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

> ...the Levenshtein distance between two words is the minimum number of single-character edits (i.e. insertions, deletions or substitutions) required to change one word into the other.

[PHP example](https://eval.in/447746):

```
$words = array(
"pale",
"male",
"sale",
"tale",
"pile",
"pole",
"pace",
"page",
"pane",
"pave",
"palm",

"peal",
"leap",
"play",
"help",
"pack"
);

foreach($words AS $word)
  if(levenshtein("pale", $word) > 1)
    echo $word."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

This assumes the word on the first line is the keyword. Just a brute force parallel letter-match and count gets the job done:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=""}
     NR==1{n=NF;for(i=1;i<=n;++i)c[i]=$i}
     NR>1{j=0;for(i=1;i<=n;++i)j+=c[i]==$i;if(j<n-1)print}'
```

A regexp general solution would need to be a 2-stepper I think -- generate the regexp in first step (from the keyword), run the regexp against the file in the second step.

By the way, the way to do an "and" of regexp's is to string lookaheads (and the lookaheads don't need to be as complicated as you had above I think):

```
^(?!.ale)(?!p.le)(?!pa.e)(?!pal.)
```